# How to approximate the time to mean reversion for implied volatility in python

Tags: options, implied-volatility, python

Its the same question as previous, except I am looking for code in python
 verses R. [How to approximate the time to mean reversion for implied volatility](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/how-to-approximate-the-time-to-mean-reversion-for-implied-volatility/16747#comment40816_16747)

Given an option and its implied volatility, and also the mean value of the implied volatility over the last 30 days, if we find that the current IV is significantly (> 1 std dev.) away from the mean, then:

How to approximate the time for the IV to mean revert in vectorized python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a python duplication with some modeled data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.formula import api

n = 1000
x = pd.date_range('2010-12-31', periods=n)
y = np.random.randn(n)
s = pd.Series(y, x)
s = np.clip(abs(s.rolling(5).mean()) + .19, 0, 1.2) * 100

df = pd.concat([s.diff(), s.shift()], axis=1, keys=['diff', 'level']).dropna()

Y = df.iloc[:, [0]].values
X = df.iloc[:, [1]].values
X = np.concatenate([np.ones_like(X), X], axis=1)

beta = np.linalg.pinv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(Y)
print(beta)

[[ 21.79316927]
 [ -0.41239735]]
```

---

***calculations***

```
long_run_mean = -beta[0, 0] / beta[1, 0]
mean_reversion_speed = -beta[1, 0] * 100
halflife = -np.log(2) / beta[1, 0]

print(long_run_mean)
print(mean_reversion_speed)
print(halflife)

53.359813861
46.3557243425
1.49527850204
```

---

Use `statsmodels`

```
results = api.ols('diff ~ level', df).fit()
results.params

Intercept    24.735328
level        -0.463557
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't take credit for this but Stuart Reid over at Turing Finance (great resource) has a great [post](http://www.turingfinance.com/random-walks-down-wall-street-stochastic-processes-in-python) and [notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/StuartGordonReid/Python-Notebooks/blob/master/Stochastic%20Process%20Algorithms.ipynb) on this. Might give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This post gives an overview of two methods to calibrate an OU process (least squares and max likelihood) and gives some code in Matlab. https://www.sitmo.com/?p=134